# swiftui: detail view uses false List style (that of its parent) before it switches to the correct style (with delay)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a master-detail view with three levels. At the first level, a person is selected. At the second level, the persons' properties are shown using a grouped list with list style "InsetGroupedListStyle()"

My problem is: each time, the third level (here called "DetailView()") is displayed, it is displayed with the wrong style (the style of its parent), before it switches to the correct style with some delay.

This is a bad user experience. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

class Data : ObservableObject {
    @Published var persons: [Person] = [
        Person(id: 0, name: "Alice"),
        Person(id: 1, name: "Bob"),
    ]
        
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var data = Data()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(data.persons, id: \.self) { person in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: EditPerson(data: data, psId: person.id),
                        label: {
                                Text(person.name)
                        })
                }
                
            }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 10)
            .navigationTitle("Persons")
        }
    }
}

struct EditPerson: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: Data
    
    var psId: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List() {
            
            Section(header:
                        Text("HEADER1 ")
            ) {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(data: data),
                    label: {
                            Text("1st link")
                    }
                )
            }
            
        }.navigationTitle("Person #" + String(psId))
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle()) // <--- the style specified here
                                            // is preliminarily used for the DetailView, too.
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data : Data

    var body: some View {
        List {  // <- this list is displayed with grouped list style before
                // it is updated some split seconds later
            Button(action: {
                print("button1 pressed")
            }) {
                Text("Button1")
            }
            Button(action: {
                print("button2 pressed")
            }) {
                Text("Button2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can’t really answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have included the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work if you simply explicitly set it back to `PlainListStyle` in `DetailView()`:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data : Data

    var body: some View {
        List {  // <- this list is displayed with grouped list style before
                // it is updated some split seconds later
            Button(action: {
                print("button1 pressed")
            }) {
                Text("Button1")
            }
            Button(action: {
                print("button2 pressed")
            }) {
                Text("Button2")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle()) // Explicitly set it here
    }
}
```

Comment: Please accept it as the answer if it works for you.